# Page not found in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have installed the `wordpress` inside the domain with in a `folder name`, `questions`, landing page is working fine, no other `links` working, its say `page not found`. what to do ??

Using .htaccess like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . questions/ [L]
```

Its running the index.php page only. any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you'll need rewritebase as you have an htaccess on your parent folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /questions/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /questions/ [L]
```

---

Are you putting this on a subfolder of the root of the site called /questions?

if yes, I think you'll need to change

```
RewriteRule . questions/ [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule . /questions/ [L]
```

or try this instead of rewritebase

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /questions/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i have tried this one as well, no change, here is the URL, http://admissiontimes.com/questions/

Comment: it could be that there is an htaccess above that folder. can you see if a file overwrites your htaccess.

Comment: and are you sure mod_rewrite is really enabled on this server? do you have other blogs hosted and if yes, do they work on their htaccess setup?

Comment: Yes it does overwrite the old one successfully, how do i can check mod_rewrite is enabled or not ??

Comment: if there is an htaccess above then you'll need rewritebase.  RewriteBase /questions/